# take liquibase scripts not from resource folder during unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, junit, liquibase

I have a following project structure

```
bin
  start.sh
db
  liquibase_scripts
    ...
    schema.json
main
  java
    ...
test
  resources
    liquibase_scripts
      ...
      schema.json
```

So than I build my project, folder db with liquibase scripts added to distributive.
In unit tests I use H2 database and want to load schema from db/liquibase. I create bean

```
    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase springLiquibase() {
        SpringLiquibase springLiquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        springLiquibase.setDataSource(dataSource());
        springLiquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:/liquibase/sam.json");
        return springLiquibase;
    }
```

The problem is that method setChangeLog look at resource folder in test folder.
So to solve the problem I copied all liquibase scripts to the test/resources directory.
But this is not ok becouse now I have 2 copies of scripts in different folders.

Is there a way to force springLiquibase.setChangeLog find scripts in any folder not only in test/resources?

Comment: Are you using any build automation tool like Maven?

Comment: @Jonasz, yes, I use Maven in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Maven build configuration you can define `testResources`, which may be directories and files. It looks like this:

```xml
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/db/liquibase_scripts</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>
```

With such configuration Maven copies the files into the `target/test-classes` directory. Thanks to that those files can be used as test resources in the code, but there's no duplication in the project files.

Im using such configuration (Liquibase + testResources) in one of my projects. To better reproduce your problem, I've created [a separate branch](https://github.com/Jonarzz/refactoring-katas/tree/stack-overlow-answers/73301167), where you can find the configuration described above - see: [this commit diff](https://github.com/Jonarzz/refactoring-katas/commit/f9ebbadefcdae5146bb53f0fff4c777439f77897). All test pass after the change.